# In what situation do we need to use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered`?

Tags: python

The ordering of results from the returned iterator of `imap_unordered` is arbitrary, and it doesn't seem to run faster than `imap`(which I check with the following code), so why would one use this method?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def square(i):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return i ** 2

p = Pool(4)
nums = range(50)

start = time.time()
print 'Using imap'
for i in p.imap(square, nums):
    pass
print 'Time elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
print 'Using imap_unordered'
for i in p.imap_unordered(square, nums):
    pass
print 'Time elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - start)
```

Comment: In this example, the difference between the amount of time required for `0**2` is not that different from `49**2`. I'm wondering what would happen if some calculation takes much longer time than the others. Will `imap_unordered` be faster in such a case?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using `pool.imap_unordered` instead of `pool.imap` will not have a large effect on the total running time of your code. It might be a little faster, but not by too much.

What it may do, however, is make the interval between values being available in your iteration more even. That is, if you have operations that can take very different amounts of time (rather than the consistent `0.01` seconds you were using in your example), `imap_unordered` can smooth things out by yielding faster-calculated values ahead of slower-calculated values. The regular `imap` will delay yielding the faster ones until after the slower ones ahead of them have been computed (but this does not delay the worker processes moving on to more calculations, just the time for you to see them).

Try making your work function sleep for `i*0.1` seconds, shuffling your input list and printing `i` in your loops. You'll be able to see the difference between the two `imap` versions. Here's my version (the `main` function and the `if __name__ == '__main__'` boilerplate was is required to run correctly on Windows):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random

def work(i):
    time.sleep(0.1*i)
    return i

def main():
    p = Pool(4)
    nums = range(50)
    random.shuffle(nums)

    start = time.time()
    print 'Using imap'
    for i in p.imap(work, nums):
        print i
    print 'Time elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - start)

    start = time.time()
    print 'Using imap_unordered'
    for i in p.imap_unordered(work, nums):
        print i
    print 'Time elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `imap` version will have long pauses while values like 49 are being handled (taking 4.9 seconds), then it will fly over a bunch of other values (which were calculated by the other processes while we were waiting for 49 to be processed). In contrast, the `imap_unordered` loop will usually not pause nearly as long at one time. It will have more frequent, but shorter pauses, and its output will tend to be smoother.

Comment: jup, so it’s ideal for e.g. displaying a progressbar for completed tasks.

Comment: for python 3 use `print()` and change range line to `nums = list(range(50))`  Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @flyingsheep `imap_unordered` returns results in *arbitrary* order, not *completion* order.

Comment: @Booboo: I think the arbitrary order that `imap_unoredered` uses *is* the completion order. The arbitrariness is that it may not be the same order as the data was originally in. It can sometimes be the same, but some items might be reordered if they took different amounts of time to process.

Comment: @Blckknght I have experimented with this and if you specify a *chunksize* argument value of 1 (or take the default, `None`, which results in using a value of 1), then it *appears* that the results are returned in completion order. But when I have used a larger *chunksize* value, that has *not* been the case. If you wish I can post a trivial program that demonstrates this.

Comment: Sure, but it's likely to be completion order, by chunk. Which differs even more from the order the input was in, but still isn't entirely arbitrary (the result based on the first value in the input will still be yielded before the last one, in almost every case, unless runtime of the jobs varies extremely widely). Anyway, exactly what the order will be is usually not something you should care about if using `imap_unoredered` because whatever it is, it is an implementation detail, so there are no guarantees.

Comment: without imap_unordered, the results are FIFO? 1 task stuck in front means all completed results have to wait?

Comment: @Dee: Yes, the iterator from `imap` in the main process delays yielding completed results if they're out of order. The other processes will keep calculating further values regardless of an earlier one being stalled, but they won't be yielded out of order unless you used `imap_unordered`. If you have a permanently stuck task, that's going to cause issues for both functions, as the iteration will never end (though `imap_unordered` will yield most of the successfully completed results before blocking).

Answer (score 13):

imap_unordered also seems to use less memory over time than imap. At least that's what I experienced with a iterator over millions of things.

Comment: That would be because it doesn't need to hold onto as many items that were completed ahead of when they are used.